# Cannot perform click on the hidden control coded ui VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

Cannot perform click on the hidden control coded ui VS2015

Additional Details:

Technology Name :"MSAA"

Control Type: "Image"

Comment: This is not really a question or enough information to really help.  That said, you cannot click on hidden elements so...?

Comment: in coded UI after i record and do play back the code breaks on Mouse.Click(uIItemImage, new Point(164, 42)); On debugging this is the error I get

Comment: Is the image visible when it tries to replay?  And is it on screen?  Sometimes the window will start not maximized and the thing you are trying to click will be hidden.

Comment: yes the Image is there

Comment: Maybe you're searching for something else and looking at something different... Make sure you've supplied the correct search properties...

Comment: for cross browser testing we need to install selenium based components. Else code UI will best work with IE.